# tflearnのRNNへの入力データで、timestepsはどのような用途に使いますか？

Tags: tensorflow, 機械学習, keras

tensorflowにてRNNの勉強をしています。
今はtflearnを使用しての実装をお試ししています。

下記の通りlstm,gru,...APIに渡すInputのTensorの形は`[samples, timesteps, input dim]`となっています。
http://tflearn.org/layers/recurrent/

この内timestepsの用途が理解できておりません。

RNNはそもそも以前の入力をメモリに覚えているので、
1回1回の入力データとして過去のデータを渡す必要がないという理解です。
事実timestepsを`[1]`にして、当該の入力データしか渡さない場合もうまく学習できています。

timestepsはどのような用途に使うのでしょうか？

コードはこちらのサイトを参考にして勉強しております。
https://deepage.net/deep_learning/2016/09/17/tflearn_rnn.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

すみません、自己解決しました。

timestepsが1の場合はRNNになっておらず、普通のニューラルネットワークと同じパラの学習をしていますね。
試しに過去データに依存が強いような入力列にしてみたら全く機能しませんでした。

参考サイトだとtimestepsに1が指定されていることが多いので誤解していました。